# Netbeans 7.2 suddenly has CPU spikes and slows down completely

Tags: cpu, netbeans

When I first installed **Netbeans 7.2** everything was pretty smooth. But for the past couple of days I've noticed that after a few hours of usage the CPU usage begins to spike to unbearable levels. Forcing me to restart the application.

Here is a screenshot:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/JimCA.png]

I haven't installed anything besides package manager updates, which I guess should be the first place to look. But I was hoping someone might also have seen this issue and would know what I should look into.

Answer (score 0):

I installed NetBeans 7.2 on Ubuntu 12.04 (using .sh file downloaded from NetBenas site and Oracle JDK) and do not have this problem. Do you use OpenJDK? I may caused by OpenJDK.